# How do I add a toast notification (or similar) to a card?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-workspace, card

I am trying to modify the [cats quickstart](https://developers.google.com/workspace/add-ons/cats-quickstart?hl=en) tutorial to add a notification at the bottom to notify the user when any errors are encountered (e.g. a toast notification or something similar).

I have:

```
function createCatCard(text, isHomepage) {
  if (!isHomepage) {
    isHomepage = false;
  }

  // Use the "Cat as a service" API to get the cat image. Add a "time" URL
  // parameter to act as a cache buster.
  var now = new Date();
  // Replace formward slashes in the text, as they break the CataaS API.
  var caption = text.replace(/\//g, ' ');
  var imageUrl = Utilities.formatString('https://cataas.com/cat/says/%s?time=%s', encodeURIComponent(caption), now.getTime());
  var image = CardService.newImage().setImageUrl(imageUrl).setAltText('Meow')

  // Create a button that changes the cat image when pressed.
  // Note: Action parameter keys and values must be strings.
  var action = CardService.newAction().setFunctionName('onChangeCat').setParameters({text: text, isHomepage: isHomepage.toString()});
  var button = CardService.newTextButton().setText('Change cat').setOnClickAction(action).setTextButtonStyle(CardService.TextButtonStyle.FILLED);
  var buttonSet = CardService.newButtonSet().addButton(button);

  // Create a footer to be shown at the bottom.
  var footer = CardService.newFixedFooter().setPrimaryButton(CardService.newTextButton().setText('Powered by cataas.com').setOpenLink(CardService.newOpenLink().setUrl('https://cataas.com')));

  // Assemble the widgets and return the card.
  var section = CardService.newCardSection().addWidget(image).addWidget(buttonSet);
  var card = CardService.newCardBuilder().addSection(section).setFixedFooter(footer);

  if (!isHomepage) {
    // Create the header shown when the card is minimized,
    // but only when this card is a contextual card. Peek headers
    // are never used by non-contexual cards like homepages.
    var peekHeader = CardService.newCardHeader().setTitle('Contextual Cat').setImageUrl('https://www.gstatic.com/images/icons/material/system/1x/pets_black_48dp.png').setSubtitle(text);
    card.setPeekCardHeader(peekHeader)
  }

  var act = CardService.newActionResponseBuilder().setNotification(CardService.newNotification().setText('bob here').setType(CardService.NotificationType.INFO));
  card.addCardAction(act);


  return card.build();
}
```

(The only part I've added is the second to last line). However, when I run the code, I get:

`Cannot find method addCardAction(CardService.ActionResponseBuilder). [line: 62, function: createCatCard, file: Common]`

EDIT:

I've also tried `card.setNotification(CardService.newNotification().setText('bob here').setType(CardService.NotificationType.INFO));` but I get `TypeError: Cannot find function setNotification in object CardBuilder. [line: 62, function: createCatCard, file: Common]`

EDIT2:
I've also tried

```
card.newNotification().setText('bob here').setType(CardService.NotificationType.INFO);
```

but I get `TypeError: Cannot find function newNotification in object CardBuilder. [line: 63, function: createCatCard, file: Common]`

Comment: whats the status code when it doesn't give expected return?

Answer (score 3):

The `card` object is of the type `CardBuilder`, and according to the [docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/card-builder?hl=en), it does not have an `addCardAction`, `setNotification`, or `newNotification` method, which is why what you are trying to do won't work.
There is a [Notification](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/notification?hl=en) class, that you use when a user interacts with a UI element." Here is an example for the cats quickstart code:

```
function onChangeCat(e) {
    ... // <-- omitted for brevity
    var navigation = CardService.newNavigation()
        .updateCard(card);
    var actionResponse = CardService.newActionResponseBuilder()
        .setNavigation(navigation);
    const failed = someOperationThatMightFail();
    if (failed) {
         actionResponse
        .setNotification(CardService.newNotification()
        .setText("PANIC"));
    }
    return actionResponse.build();
}
```

Edit:
If you want to indicate a failure using your existing card I believe it has to be done with the actual Card object itself. The `Notification` class can only be used as a response to interactions with UI elements. An advantage of indicating a failure with the `Card` object is that the information will be available to the user until the problem has been resolved, unlike with the `Notification` which will eventually disappear from the UI.
Here is an example of how you could indicate failure using your existing card:

```
function createCatCard(text, isHomepage) {
    ...
    // Create a footer to be shown at the bottom.
    var footer = CardService.newFixedFooter().setPrimaryButton(CardService.newTextButton().setText('Powered by cataas.com').setOpenLink(CardService.newOpenLink().setUrl('https://cataas.com')));

    // Assemble the widgets and return the card.
    var section = CardService.newCardSection();

    const failed = someOperationThatMightFail();
    if (failed) {
        var textParagraph = CardService.newTextParagraph();
        textParagraph.setText('Something went wrong, please try again later');
        section
            .addWidget(buttontextParagraphSet);
    } else {
        section
            .addWidget(image)
            .addWidget(buttonSet);
    }

    var card = CardService.newCardBuilder().addSection(section).setFixedFooter(footer);

    if (!isHomepage) {
        // Create the header shown when the card is minimized,
        // but only when this card is a contextual card. Peek headers
        // are never used by non-contexual cards like homepages.
       var peekHeader = CardService.newCardHeader().setTitle('Contextual Cat').setImageUrl('https://www.gstatic.com/images/icons/material/system/1x/pets_black_48dp.png').setSubtitle(text);
       card.setPeekCardHeader(peekHeader)
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to combine it with the existing card I have?

Comment: Wish I could get the notification but seems like the best I'm gonna be able to do. Thanks!